# HDD turns off and on intermittently

Tags: hard-drive, bsod, sata, troubleshooting, reboot

I recently bought an internal Seagate HDD (ST1000DM010). Initially I plugged it in a secondary computer (Intel DH55HC motherboard, Q4'09) and then proceeded to install Windows 8 from an USB. During the installation process a blue screen of death appeared; I retried several times but always got the same result. In each try the BSOD appeared at different times, sometimes 25 seconds after start, sometimes after 3 minutes.

Being aware that I won't be able to complete the installation that way, I booted up Windows 8 from a live USB and ran HD Tune benchmarks, but at the middle (less or more) of the tests, they failed. After that, I checked HDD health with CrystalDiskInfo and noticed that it had *1 power on hour* but about *450 power on counts*.

After that, I realised the reason why the OS installation and benchmark failed was because it was constantly turning off and on. Then I paid attention to the computer noises and that was true.

Some other things I tried but nothing changed:

- Change the SATA cable.
- Change the SATA port were the HDD was plugged in
- Change the power cord from the PSU

I don't know were the problem would be; maybe a defective unit ?

I'd like to read your thoughts about it, I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

please check the power consumption of your system and the power reading it your power supply.
But most probably it's a defective unit, in my opinion.